# Cant install tensorflow for huggingface transformers library

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, package, huggingface-transformers

Im trying to use huggingface transformers library in my python project. I am a first time python programmer, and I am stuck on this error message, even though tensorflow has been installed on my machine:

```python
>>> from transformers import pipeline

None of PyTorch, TensorFlow >= 2.0, or Flax have been found. Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data utilities can be used.
```

I have discovered that tensorflow does not exist, even though I have installed it via `pip`. I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it, and but when I try to import the package, it just comes back as a `ModuleNotFoundError`

```py
>>> import tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\######\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing using `pip` and `conda`. I even tried installing `pytorch` using the same methods. It always says that the package was succesfully installed, and yet the error persists.

I am using Python 3.9 and my OS is Windows 10. I dont know what I am doing wrong. But I know that a solution will definitely not be to uninstall and reinstall a package.

**Pip version (`pip -V`):**

```
pip 21.1.3 from c:\users\######\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

**Python version (`python -V`):**

```
Python 3.9.5
```

**Python path list**
I tried comparing the output of `sys.path` with the output of `pip -V`.
The closest path I saw for the `pip -V` path is down at the bottom, however I did not find the exact directory.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path

['', 'C:\\windows\\system32', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\######\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Users\\######\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Closest path:

```
C:\Users\######\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages
```

Comment: If it is installed, can you run `import tensorflow` before `from transformers ...`?

Comment: You have multiple python interpreters installed, that is why installing stuff does not show in your python  interpreter, use  pip -V and compare it to the python version that appears in the interpreter (when you run python)

Comment: Also running commands randomly without understanding what they do and if they apply to you, is not going to help you learn.

Comment: Not necessarily, do the following, open a python interpreter, import sys, and then call sys.path and compare with the output of pip -V

Comment: Also it would be good to post the whole traceback that is produced when you import TensorFlow.

Comment: That is because as I initially said, you have two python interpreters installed, remove one and use only one.

Comment: I am talking about removing one of your python interpreters, you should know how they were installed, I am not talking about pip.

Comment: It worked!!! I just needed to uninstall both my interpreters, and reinstall one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments

> You have multiple python interpreters installed, that is why
> installing stuff does not show in your python interpreter, use `pip -V` and compare it to the python version that appears in the interpreter. Remove one and use only one then your issue will be
> resolved (paraphrased from Dr.Snoopy)